# Route Param not working with React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router, routeparams

I am trying to use Route params but I cannot get the params.

The page simply shows nothing, seems like undefined or blank.

How do I get the param from "wedding/:pageName"?

What is missing here? Is it the best way to get params?

The "pageName" is not ID, is it a problem?

Thanks in advance

My App.js

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../actions';

import Header from './Header';
import Weddings from './Weddings';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div className="container">
            <Header />
            <Route path="/wedding/:pageName" component={Wedding} />
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, actions)(App);
```

Wedding.js

```html
import React from 'react';
import WeddingPage from './weddings/WeddingPage';

const Wedding = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <WeddingPage />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Wedding;
```

WeddingPage.js

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class WeddingPage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.pageName}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default WeddingPage;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you aren't passing props through from `Wedding` to `WeddingPage`.

`Wedding.js` needs to accept and pass `props` to it's child:

```
import React from 'react';
import WeddingPage from './weddings/WeddingPage';

const Wedding = props => {
    return (
        <div>
            <WeddingPage {...props} />
        </div>
    );
}

export default Wedding;
```

`WeddingPage.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class WeddingPage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.match.params.pageName}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default WeddingPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

With react router, you can access the router params as this.props.match.params.pageName

Comment: Did not work. I got the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

In your case, first you need to get pageName params in `Wedding` component like 
`this.props.match.params.pageName` 
and than further pass pageName props to weddingPage component like 
`<WeddingPage pageName={this.props.match.params.pageName} />`

Comment: I have tried this, but did not work. I got this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined"